# Check if a given set of vectors is the basis of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

I'm given the following basis: $\beta = \{1 + X, 1 + X², X + X²\}$ and we are asked to verify that this is a basis for the vectorspace $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq2}, +)$. Now the definition of a basis says that $\beta$ is a basis for a vectorspace iff $\beta$ is linearly independent and $span<\beta>$ $= \mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq2}$.

I thus set out to prove the two properties. The first part of my question is more verification that the following method is allowed. I interpreted the basis to be of the form $\beta = \{(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)\}$ and solved the following linear systems of equations to check if the vectors of the basis are indeed linearly independant (the unknown variables are in the end represented as $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$):

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & | & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & | & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & | & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{matrix} ~ \\ \xrightarrow{R_2 \rightarrow R_2 - R_1}\end{matrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & | & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & | & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & | & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{matrix} ~ \\ \xrightarrow{R_3 \rightarrow R_3 + R_2}\end{matrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & | & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & | & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & | & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

From this matrix I could see that using backwards substitution, the values of $\lambda_3 = 0, \lambda_2 = 0$ and $\lambda_1 = 0$ and thus that the vectors are indeed linearly independent of each other.

The second part of the problem however I have no idea how to check. Is there a general method for checking if any basis spans the vectorspace? I have tried to look for this but cannot seem to find a satisfying answer to the question in proof-form. Any hint at how to start would already be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{1,X,X^{2}\}$ is a basis for your space. So the space is three dimensional. This implies that any three linearly independent vectors automatically span the space.

Comment: I don't need to find a new basis of the space, I need to verify that the given basis actually spans the space. Isn't there a difference is this?

Comment: It spans the space automatically. You don't have to do any more work.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see how $\{1 + X, 1 + X^2, X + X^2\}$ would span this same space. Is there any trick in seeing this?

Comment: You don't have to take any element in the space and prove that it is a linear combination of these three. You are free to use  the theorem I have quoted in my answer.

Comment: Oh it is a theorem? It is nowhere mentioned in my book but I will keep this in mind since it'll probably prove useful in the future as well! Thanks!